# Multi-tree and Priority Ordering Algorithm

Tags: java, performance, sorting, recursion

I would like advice on an algorithm for ordering data.

## Problem


I need to sort a list of records (POJOs) based on several criteria.

1. Parent child relationship (no inheritance, just properties)
2. A unique ordering id (*unique* within a generational level of each tree).

Each record has the following properties:

- **ID** - uniquely identifies each record
- **Parent ID** - Identifies the record's parent. If same as id, this is a top level root node
- **Order Number** - orders children within the same generation/family.

Example Records. They are not always in nice numerical order ;)

[image]
And after they are sorted:
[image]
Please note, record 14 is before record 5 because of its Order Number (priority).

In my dataset, there are approximately 3,000 records, and usually no more than 3 or 4 levels of depth.

---

## Strategy


Start with two lists:
 1. The list that contains the records to be ordered.
 2. An empty list to hold all sorted records

**Step 1**: Loop through the records and grab all top level nodes (id=parent id), sort them by Order Number, then add them to the second list.
**Step 2**: *For each node* in list 2, loop through list 1 and grab all children, sort them by Order Number, then insert them in list 2 directly after their parent.
Note that pretty much all the sorting happens in step 2.

Here is a run through.

### [image]

## Questions


I believe step 2 will make the algorithm complexity at least O(n²).
What are the pros and cons of this algorithm versus something like recursion?
Is there a more efficient algorithm to use?

Comment: Efficiency and optimal algorithm depends on how many records there might be and how deep the tree might go.

Comment: Thanks Mikelis. I have added that information.

Comment: And step 2 is not that easy. How do u imagine "_insert them in list 2 directly after their parent_"? You could loop through array x times where x is the tree height (how deep it goes). First time you take only those that are in first level (`id=parent_id`). Second time you take only those that are under first level (`all_parent_ids_array.indexOf(id)>0`), third time -(`all_second_level_elem_ids_array.indexOf(id)>0`) etc. In first level you add them and create them also a `map` of orders(children). Do the same for all levels. There will be some elements with their values, but empty children map.

Comment: We are not grabbing all children for _every_ parent in each loop. We are grabbing all children for the _current_ parent.

Comment: The nested loops make the complexity quadratic . A solution based on populating  a tree structure and then flattening it to give you the required list would involve a series of tree traversals which require linear time . As said above If the number of elements you expect to be dealing with is large then choosing O(n) over O(n^2) becomes more of an issue .

Answer (score 0):

It's late but i think i got it :)

```
List<Pojo> list = Arrays.asList(
        new Pojo(1,1,1),new Pojo(2,1,1),
        new Pojo(3,2,1),new Pojo(4,3,1),new Pojo(5,2,3),
        new Pojo(6,5,1),new Pojo(7,6,1),new Pojo(8,1,2),
        new Pojo(9,9,2),new Pojo(10,9,2),new Pojo(11,9,1),
        new Pojo(12,11,1),new Pojo(13,13,3),new Pojo(14,2,2)
);
```

First sort by parent and orderNumber:

```
Collections.sort(list, (a,b) -> {

    if ( a.id == a.pId && a.pId == b.pId ) return -1;
    if ( b.id == b.pId && a.pId == b.pId ) return  1;

    // 100000... a number bigger there largest order#
    int aa = 100000 * a.pId + a.oNo;
    int bb = 100000 * b.pId + b.oNo;

    if ( aa > bb ) return  1;
    if ( aa < bb ) return -1;

    return 0;
});
```

Then loop forward and for each line traverse back to where another pojo has the same parentId or where the other pojo's id is equal to the traversing pojo's parentId:

```
for ( int fw = 1 ; fw < list.size() ; fw ++ )
{
    Pojo a = list.get(fw);

    if ( a.id != a.pId )
    {
        for ( int bw = fw - 1 ; bw >= 0 ; bw -- )
        {
            Pojo b = list.get(bw);

            if ( a.pId != b.pId && a.pId != b.id )
            {
                list.set(bw, a);
                list.set(bw+1, b);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which relies on tree traversal as referred to in the comment above.This gives a linear time performance which will become more relevant as the dataset size increases.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public  class PriorityTree {

    static class Node<T extends Comparable> implements Comparable{
        private T data;
        private Node<T> parent;
        private Collection<Node<T>> children;
        BiPredicate<Node<T>,T> addNodePredicate;
        UnaryOperator<T> paddingElement;

        public Node(T data, Node<T> parent, Collection<Node<T>> children,BiPredicate<Node<T>,T> addNodePredicate,UnaryOperator<T> paddingElement) {
            this.data = data;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.children = children;
            this.addNodePredicate = addNodePredicate;
            this.paddingElement = paddingElement;
        }

        public Node(T data, Node<T> parent) {
            this(data,parent,new TreeSet<Node<T>>(),parent.addNodePredicate,parent.paddingElement);
        }

        public boolean add(T element) {
            if (this.addNodePredicate.test(this,element)) {
                this.children.add(new Node<T>(element, this));
                return true;
            } else {
                for (Node<T> node : this.children) {
                    if(node.add(element)) return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        private String print(String indent){
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append(indent);
            stringBuilder.append(data);
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
            for (Node<T> node : this.children) {
                stringBuilder.append(node.print(indent+"  "));
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return print("");
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            return this.data.compareTo(((Node<T>)o).data);
        }
    }

    static class Pojo implements Comparable{
        int id;
        int parentId;
        final int orderNo;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "id=["+id + "],parentId=["+parentId+"],orderNo=["+orderNo+"]";
        }

        public Pojo(int id, int parentId, int orderNo) {
            this(orderNo);
            this.parentId = parentId;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Pojo(int orderNo) {
            this.orderNo = orderNo;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getParentId() {
            return parentId;
        }

        public int getOrderNo() {
            return orderNo;
        }

        public int compareTo(Object that) {
            if (that == null )return 1;
            if ( that instanceof Pojo)
                return Integer.compare(this.getOrderNo(),((Pojo)that).getOrderNo());
            else return 1;
        }

        static Pojo ROOT= new Pojo(0,0,0);

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            Pojo pojo = (Pojo) o;

            if (id != pojo.id) return false;
            if (parentId != pojo.parentId) return false;
            return orderNo == pojo.orderNo;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = id;
            result = 31 * result + parentId;
            result = 31 * result + orderNo;
            return result;
        }
    }


    private static List<Pojo> readInObjects(String csvFile){
        final List<Pojo> list = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
        try{
            final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(csvFile);
            final BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            while (( line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                final String[] valueArray = line.split(",");
                final int id = Integer.parseInt(valueArray[0]);
                final int parentId = Integer.parseInt(valueArray[1]);
                final int orderNo = Integer.parseInt(valueArray[2]);
                final Pojo pojo = new Pojo(id,parentId,orderNo);
                list.add(pojo);
            }

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final List<Pojo> values = readInObjects("values.txt");
        final Node<Pojo> tree = new Node<>(Pojo.ROOT, null, new TreeSet<>(), (pojoNode, pojo) -> pojoNode.data.getId()==0 && pojo.getId()==pojo.getParentId() ||pojoNode.data.getId() == pojo.getParentId(),(p)->new Pojo(0,p.getId(),0));
        values.stream().forEach(pojo -> tree.add(pojo));
        System.out.println(tree.toString());
    }
}
```

values.txt has the following entries

```
1,1,1
2,1,1
3,2,1
4,3,1
5,2,3
6,5,1
7,6,1
8,1,2
9,9,2
10,9,2
11,9,1
12,11,1
13,13,3
14,2,2
```

Output looks like

```
id=[1],parentId=[1],orderNo=[1]
  id=[2],parentId=[1],orderNo=[1]
    id=[3],parentId=[2],orderNo=[1]
      id=[4],parentId=[3],orderNo=[1]
    id=[14],parentId=[2],orderNo=[2]
    id=[5],parentId=[2],orderNo=[3]
      id=[6],parentId=[5],orderNo=[1]
        id=[7],parentId=[6],orderNo=[1]
  id=[8],parentId=[1],orderNo=[2]
id=[9],parentId=[9],orderNo=[2]
  id=[11],parentId=[9],orderNo=[1]
    id=[12],parentId=[11],orderNo=[1]
  id=[10],parentId=[9],orderNo=[2]
id=[13],parentId=[13],orderNo=[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working sorting example in C++, hope this helps

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct TreeElement {
    uint32_t id;
    uint32_t idx;
    uint32_t parent;

    [[nodiscard]]
    bool operator==(const TreeElement& other) const noexcept {
        return id == other.id && idx == other.idx && parent == other.parent;
    }
};

void elem_swap(TreeElement& first, TreeElement& second) {
    TreeElement tmp = first;
    first           = second;
    second          = tmp;
}

// returns number of processed elements
uint32_t emplace_children(TreeElement* elements, size_t count, uint32_t parent) {
    if(!count) {
        return 0;
    }

    uint32_t i = 0;
    for(; i < count; ++i) {
        uint32_t     lowestChildIdx = 0;
        bool         found          = false;
        for(uint32_t j              = i; j < count; ++j) {
            if(elements[j].parent == parent) {
                if(!found || elements[j].idx <= elements[lowestChildIdx].idx) {
                    lowestChildIdx = j;
                }
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if(!found) {
            return i;
        }

        elem_swap(elements[i], elements[lowestChildIdx]);

        i += emplace_children(elements + i + 1, count - i - 1, elements[i].id);
    }

    return i;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<TreeElement> elements = {TreeElement{.id = 11, .idx = 03, .parent = 6},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 10, .idx = 2, .parent = 6},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 1, .idx = 0, .parent = 0},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 6, .idx = 2, .parent = 2},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 5, .idx = 1, .parent = 2},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 4, .idx = 0, .parent = 2},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 2, .idx = 0, .parent = 1},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 9, .idx = 1, .parent = 6},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 8, .idx = 0, .parent = 6},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 3, .idx = 1, .parent = 1},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 7, .idx = 0, .parent = 4},
                                         TreeElement{.id = 12, .idx = 1, .parent = 9}};


    std::vector<TreeElement> goal = {TreeElement{.id = 1, .idx = 0, .parent = 0},
                                        TreeElement{.id = 2, .idx = 0, .parent = 1},
                                            TreeElement{.id = 4, .idx = 0, .parent = 2},
                                                TreeElement{.id = 7, .idx = 0, .parent = 4},
                                            TreeElement{.id = 5, .idx = 1, .parent = 2},
                                            TreeElement{.id = 6, .idx = 2, .parent = 2},
                                                TreeElement{.id = 8, .idx = 0, .parent = 6},
                                                TreeElement{.id = 9, .idx = 1, .parent = 6},
                                                    TreeElement{.id = 12, .idx = 1, .parent = 9},
                                                TreeElement{.id = 10, .idx = 2, .parent = 6},
                                                TreeElement{.id = 11, .idx = 03, .parent = 6},
                                        TreeElement{.id = 3, .idx = 1, .parent = 1}};

    emplace_children(elements.data(), elements.size(), 0);

    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < elements.size(); ++i) {
        if(elements[i] == goal[i]) {
            std::cout << "index " << i << " passed" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "index " << i << " failed" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```